# Interfacing Twisted to other applications

Tags: twisted

I have decided to use Twisted for a project and have developed a server that can push data to clients on other computers. At the moment I am using dummy data for testing speed requirements but I now need to interface Twisted to my other Python DAQ application which basically collects real-time data (500 Hz) from various external devices over different transports (e.g. Bluetooth). (note: the DAQ (data acquisition) application is on the same computer as the Twisted server)

Since the DAQ application is not part of the Twisted framework I am wondering what is the most efficient (fastest, robust, minimal latency) way to pass the data to the Twisted server. I have considered using a light-weight database, memcache, Queue or even the Twisted plugins but it is hard to tell which would be the most appropriate and best fit. I should add that the DAQ application was developed before deciding on using Twisted so I have so far considered it as separate from the Twisted network.

On the other side of the system, the client side, which reside on multiple computers, I have a similar problem. As the data streams in (I am sending lines of data, about 100 bytes each) I want to hand this data off to another application which will process this data for a web application (I would prefer to use Twisted Web Service for this but that is not my choice!) The Web application is being written in Java. Once again I have considered the choices above but since I am new to Twisted I am not sure which is the best approach. (note: the Web application is on the same computers as the Twisted clients)

Any advice or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: DAQ stands for data acquisition.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to to [build a simple protocol with twisted's built-in support for AMP](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.protocols.amp.html); you can hook this in to any other languages or frameworks using one of the [implementations of AMP in other languages](http://amp-protocol.net/).  AMP is designed to be as easy as possible to implement, as it's just a socket with some length-prefixed strings arranged into key/value pairs.

Comment: thank you, but I may have misled you. The data acquisition (DAQ) application is on the same box as the Twisted server and the Web application (Java) is on the same box(es) as the client(s). I thought AMP was for across network calls, but I might be wrong (I suppose I could use it on the localhost loop). Apologies for my lack of clarity. If I can use Amp in this way it would be a great solution.

Comment: having read further on this I see that I can use AMP for local IPC but it would probably be best to use a transport other than TCP, if possible. Thanks again.

Comment: TCP is easy to use, and probably nearly as good as any other you'll find.  A UNIX socket might come with some security benefits, since you can have the filesystem do access control for you, but otherwise you won't notice any difference from TCP.

Answer (score 0):

There's obviously a zillion different ways you could go about this, but I would first look at using a queue to pass the data to your Twisted server.  If you deploy one of the many opensource queueing tools (e.g. RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ, OpenMQ, and loads of others), you should be able to write from your DAQ product using something generic like HTTP, then read into your Twisted server also using HTTP.  If you don't like HTTP, then there would be a lot of alternative transports to choose from - just identify which you want to use, then use that as a basis for selecting your queueing tool.

This would give you an extremely flexible solution, in that you could upgrade or change any of these products with minimal impact to anything else in the whole solution.

Comment: I looked at the first three options you mention and really like ZeroMQ but for various reasons I am trying to limit the number of applications I am running. My high data throughput might not be appropriate for HTTP (perhaps I could use websockets). AMP and PB offer built-in solutions so I am looking into both. I appreciate your suggestions. Thanks.